# What is the # in Apple's Notes Color picker? (UIAccessibility - VoiceOver)

Tags: voiceover, uiaccessibility

Apple's color picker in the notes app will list color in VoiceOver like this:

- Dark Red 29 Button
- Green 81 Button
- Cyan 74 Button

What does the number represent?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's the shade of the color. For example, Dark Red is an arbitrary name, it could mean a wide range of shades of dark red. 29, in this case, specifies which particular shade. The same goes for the rest of the colors

Comment: Yeah I think you are on the right track, but I think it's tint, not shading. White is 100, black is 0, and colors closer to white appear to have a higher value. Shading would be mixing in black, tint would be mixing in white.  I just did a quick search on color theory and I could be wrong though.